# how to access object values in php

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework2

I have an object variable like :

```
object(Zend\Authentication\Result)#271 (3) {
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(1)
  ["identity":protected]=>
  string(18) "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
  ["messages":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "Authentication successful."
  }
}
```

Here how I can access messages value in above.

Comment: `$obj->messages[0]`? just follow the "left" side of the dump for your "address" information.

Comment: Also note, the property is declared as `protected` which means it can only be accessed from within that class or extending/parent classes. You can read more about visibility at http://www.php.net/protected

Comment: I have this error : Cannot access protected property Zend\Authentication\Result::$messages

Comment: use [public getMessages()](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Authentication/Result.php#L118) with Zend\Authentication

Comment: what about reading the first tutorial that pops out when googling `php oop tutorial` ?? http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/downloads/oop_in_php_tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can't access protected properties directly, that's the point of protected properties. Your best bet is to look at the source code for the class to see what methods return those properties. In this particular case, there's a `getMessages()` method, so `$result->getMessages()` should give you the array you're after.